# terminal command to flatten folder contents

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, mv

I have a terminal command that successfully flattens the contents of current folder but it asks me to replace duplicates.

```
find ./ -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -i '{}' . \;
```

I don't want to be prompted to replace duplicates and would prefer it not replace duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `mv -i` with `mv -n`. `-i` means mv will prompt whether to overwrite existing file, and `-n` means it will not overwrite existing file.